# How to pass data to destination view when i use storyboard id?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Basically, When I want to pass data from source view to destination view, I use "prepareForSegue" Method and make destinationView equal to segue's destinationView.

But if I want to use Storyboard ID in below code to present above of my current view:

```
MyCustomViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

How can I pass data from current view to destination view by using Storyboard ID ??

Answer (score 4):

Same way..

```
MyCustomViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
vc.someProperty = something;  //use your data here
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        ViewController *objVc = [segue destinationViewController];
        objVc.objectProperty = object;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I often for finish quickly , it isn't a best practice but I use the NSUserDefaults far save data for my View without create CoustomViewController.